# Conditional probability and almost sure equality confusion

Tags: probability-theory, conditional-expectation, almost-everywhere

I initially began writing a lenghty post asking for clarification of my ideas, but decided to delete it and stick to one question that I hope might help my confusion:

We're on $(\Omega, \mathcal F, P)$. The definition of $E^{\mathcal G} X$ is a variable in $L_1(\Omega, \mathcal G, P|_{\mathcal G})$ that fulfils 
$$\forall G \in \mathcal G:\;\; \int_G E^{\mathcal G} X \;dP = \int_G X \;dP$$
Now, if I was to introduce a second variable $Y$ with the property that
$$\forall G \in \mathcal G:\;\; \int_G X\; dP = \int_G Y \;dP$$
Does this mean $Y\stackrel{a.s.}=E^{\mathcal G}X$?

The problem I have with this is that while $Y$ fits the definition of the conditional expectation. The definition only looks at behaviour of integrals over sets in $\mathcal G$, whereas by declaring their almost sure equality I am actually declaring their equality on the bigger $\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal F$ (both ignoring null sets).

Thank you very much. This is one of the times when I realize I've been misunderstanding the concepts I've been using for months and my conviction that I understand mathematics on some level just breaks down. Hope I will feel better after today!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that when we talk about the random variable $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, we consider it as an element of $L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{G},P)$. As pointed out by [sinbadh](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/277566/sinbadh), the statement that the integrals of $Y$ and $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ agree on the subsets of $\mathcal{G}$ does not necessarily tell us that $Y = E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ in the $P$-a.s. sense.

For example, if we consider $X,Y,Z \in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$ and the sub-$\sigma$-algebra $\mathcal{G} = \{\emptyset,\Omega\}$, then the agreement of the integrals of the three functions on subsets of $\mathcal{G}$ tells us that $$\displaystyle\int_{\Omega} XdP = \displaystyle\int_{\Omega} YdP =\displaystyle\int_{\Omega} ZdP \Longrightarrow E[X] = E[Y] = E[Z]$$ However, this does not necessarily tell us that $Y = Z$ in the $P$-a.s. sense (relative to either $\mathcal{F}$ or $\mathcal{G}$), as $Y$ and $Z$ could be functions that disagree wildly on $\Omega$ (and consequently differ on both subsets in $\mathcal{F}$ and subsets in $\mathcal{G}$) yet still have the same expected value. However, if we require that $Y$ and $Z$ are $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then we would find that $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$, $Y$, and $Z$ are all $P$-a.s. equal to the constant function $E[X]$ (relative to both $\mathcal{F}$ and $\mathcal{G}$).

We can further illustrate the requirement for $Y$ and $Z$ to be $\mathcal{G}$-measurable through the standard proof of the $P$-a.s. uniqueness of conditional expectation. Suppose we have $X \in L^1(\Omega,\mathcal{F},P)$, $G \subset \mathcal{F}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra, and $Y,Z \in L^1(\Omega, \mathcal{G},P)$ such that $$\forall G \in \mathcal{G}, \: \: \displaystyle\int_{G} X dP = \displaystyle\int_{G} Y dP = \displaystyle\int_{G} Z dP $$ Then, noting that $\{Z>Y\},\{Y>Z\} \in \mathcal{G}$ because $Y,Z$ are $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, we have that $$\displaystyle\int_{\{Z > Y\}} ZdP  = \displaystyle\int_{\{Z > Y\}} YdP \Longrightarrow \displaystyle\int_{\{Z > Y\}} (Z-Y)dP = 0 \Longrightarrow Z \leq Y \: \: P\mathrm{-a.s.}$$ $$\displaystyle\int_{\{Y > Z\}} ZdP  = \displaystyle\int_{\{Y > Z\}} YdP \Longrightarrow \displaystyle\int_{\{Y > Z\}} (Y-Z)dP = 0 \Longrightarrow Z \geq Y \: \: P\mathrm{-a.s.} $$ Thus we can conclude that $Y = Z$ in the $P$-a.s. sense (once again, relative to either $\sigma$-algebra).

Comment: Thanks. This might be the problem. When you say $Y=Z$ in the $P$-a.s. sense in relation to $\mathcal G$, does this mean that in the context a.s. means with relation to $\mathcal G$ and not $\mathcal F$? I don't see why.

Comment: I think what I said was misleading. For $\mathcal{G} \subset \mathcal{F}$ a sub-$\sigma$-algebra, if $Y=Z$ $P$-a.s. on subsets of $\mathcal{G}$, then i believe $Y$ and $Z$ will also agree $P$-a.s. on subsets of $\mathcal{F}$ (because, in particular $\Omega \in \mathcal{G}$, so $X$ and $Y$ agree on the whole space).

Comment: 'null subset' --> really singular? not null subsets?

Comment: Ah! We might be gettting somehwere. Or at least I am, you already are "somewhere". In an hour I'll sit down with this and see if I can now clear the mess in my mind.

Comment: @DanielCooney yes. and sooooo....?

Comment: Well I follow your reasoning, which means I can now prove my original statement (with the added measurability), yet I feel I am no closer to the understanding. Is there anything more you could say on this? I suppose the intuition is what I largely lack and what makes me feel like I don't actually understand any of it.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but the way that I try to wrap my head around conditional expectation $E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ is to think of it as the unique (up to $P$-a.s. equality) $\mathcal{G}$-measurable function $Y$ such that $\displaystyle\int_{G} X dP = \displaystyle\int_G Y d$ for each $G \in \mathcal{G}$.

Comment: For example, if you want to prove that conditional expectation is linear (i.e. $E[aX + Y | \mathcal{G}] =a E[X | \mathcal{G}]+E[Y|\mathcal{G}]$), then you can first confirm that the righthand side is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable because it contains sums and scalar multiples of $\mathcal{G}$-measurable functions (the conditional expectations). Then, $\forall G \in \mathcal{G}$, we can see that $$\int_G (aX+Y)dP = a \int_G XdP + \int_G Y dP = a  \int_G E[X|\mathcal{G}] dP + \int_G E[Y|\mathcal{G}] dP  = \int_G E[aX+Y] dP$$

Answer (score 2):

It is false. For example, if $Y=X$ and $X$ is not $\mathcal{G}$ measurable.

But, if $Y$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable and $\int_GXdP=\int_GYdP$ for all $G\in\mathcal{G}$, thus it is true that $Y=E[X|\mathcal{G}]$ a.e.

Comment: Thanks, that clears some of the confusion (and possibly answers this question). Could you elaborate on why the measurability is sufficient?

Comment: Measurabilty is sufficient by definition. If $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable, then trivially $E[X|\mathcal{G}]=X$ by defintion of conditional expectation. More general, $E[X|\mathcal{G}]=X$ iff $X$ is $\mathcal{G}$-measurable.

Comment: @DahnJahn I think you forgot to include measurability in definition of conditional expectation in your post.

Comment: @BCLC: Well I didn't, by "is such that" I only wanted to include the (what seemed to me as) relevant part of the definition, keeping in mind that we all know that it has to be measurable. I'll add that to the question.

Comment: @sinbadh I agree that if $X$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, we get that equality. But I'm talking about $Y$ - if $Y$ is $\mathcal G$-measurable, I don't see how we get the equality $Y\stackrel {a.s.} = E^{\mathcal G} X$directly from the definition of conditional expectance.